# Can RFID blocking wallet corrupt a flashdrive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My flash drive recently became corrupted. The only thing I can think of that changed is that I recently have a RFID blocking wallet in my purse next to where I place the flash drive when I bring it back and forth to work. Could there be anything in the wallet corrupting the flash drive?

Answer (score 2):

Logically... no. They are passive devices (kind of like a miniature faraday cage). Modern flash drives are *pretty* robust so, chances are that its something else.

Its much more likely the system or USB port you plugged it into failed to do its job correctly